# How to configure mypy to ignore a stub file for a specific module?

Tags: python, mypy, dnspython

I installed a "dnspython" package with "pip install dnspython" under Ubuntu 22.10 and made a following short script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import dns.zone
import dns.query

zone = dns.zone.Zone("example.net")
dns.query.inbound_xfr("10.0.0.1", zone)

for (name, ttl, rdata) in zone.iterate_rdatas("SOA"):
    serial_nr = rdata.serial
```

When I check this code snippet with mypy(version 0.990), then it reports an `error: Module has no attribute "inbound_xfr"  [attr-defined]` for line number 7.

According to [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#how-imports-are-found), if a Python file and a stub file are both present in the same directory on the search path, then only the stub file is used. In case of "dnspython", the stub file `query.pyi` is present in the `dns` package and the stub file indeed has no attribute "inbound_xfr". When I rename or remove the stub file, then the `query.py` Python file is used instead of the stub file and mypy no longer complains about missing attribute.

I guess this is a "dnspython" bug? Is there a way to tell to mypy that for `query` module, the stub file should be ignored?

Comment: I'd advice to install from git main branch, where they removed stub files and started using inline annotations. There is no `query.pyi` near [implementation](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/master/dns/query.py) (though there still is one on branch 2.2)

Comment: [try exclude first](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_codes.html#silencing-errors-based-on-error-codes) and/or add additional import statement `from dns.query import inbound_xfr` and use directly `inbound_xfr()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend ignoring only the specific wrong line, not the whole module.

```py
dns.query.inbound_xfr("10.0.0.1", zone)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
```

This will suppress `attr-defined` error message that is generated on that line. If you're going to take this approach, I'd also recommend running mypy with the `--warn-unused-ignores` flag, which will report any redundant and unused `# type: ignore` statements (for example, after updating the library).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to tell to mypy that for query module, the stub file should be ignored?

No. [Stub files have precedence over modules.](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html?highlight=pyi#how-imports-are-found) Even if you pass the entire path of the stub file to `--exclude`, it will still see it.

You want to disable a language construct created specifically for definitions, which doesn't seem very logical.

> I guess this is a "dnspython" bug?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is a option [`--exclude PATTERN`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-exclude) to ignore files or directory to check.

According that doc, you should use [`--follow-imports`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#following-imports) option to **skip** the import module checked by `mypy`:

> In particular, --exclude does not affect mypy’s import following.

> You can use a per-module follow_imports config option to additionally avoid mypy from following imports and checking code you do not wish to be checked.

Another way, you could configure the *Stub files* in a specific directory, and using it by [`export MYPYPATH`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html#stub-files).